# Actualización de archivo .json agrega un campo id Undefined

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo un proyecto en react admin que se comunica con un servicio que controla la acciones CRUD del proyecto.
Los datos se obtienen de un archivo data.json con este formato:

```
{
  "config": {
    "formattedDate": "",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "email": "",
    "dropDown": "",
    "Radiocategory": "",
    "checkBox": [""]
  }
 }
```

Al realizar una actualización al archivo desde mi dataProvider se actualiza pero me agrega un campo ID : Undefined
No quiero que cree este campo y tampoco entiendo por qué me lo crea.
Esta es la parte del dataProvider:

```
update: async (resource, params) => {

    if (resource === 'config') {

      try {

        const url = 'http://192.168.0.23:4002/config';

        const response = await axios.put(url, { data: params.data });

    console.log(params.data)

        if (!response.data.config) {

          throw new Error('La respuesta no contiene la propiedad "config".');

        }



        // Devolver el mismo objeto que recibimos en los parámetros

        return { data: params.data };

      } catch (error) {

        console.error('Error al actualizar el registro:', error.message, error.response);

        throw new Error('Error al actualizar el registro');

      }

    }

  },
```

Y esto está en el server.js:

```
app.put('/config', (req, res) => {

  const { data } = req.body;



  fs.readFile(dataPath, 'utf8', (err, fileData) => {

    if (err) {

      console.error('Error al leer el archivo data.json', err);

      res.status(500).send('Error interno del servidor');

      return;

    }



    try {

      const jsonData = JSON.parse(fileData);



      // Actualizar la propiedad 'config' con los nuevos datos

      jsonData.config = data;



      // Escribir de nuevo el archivo con los datos actualizados

      fs.writeFile(dataPath, JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 2), 'utf8', writeErr => {

        if (writeErr) {

          console.error('Error al escribir en el archivo data.json', writeErr);

          res.status(500).send('Error interno del servidor');

          return;

        }



        // Respuesta modificada para incluir la información actualizada del recurso

        res.json({ config: jsonData.config });

      });

    } catch (jsonError) {

      console.error('Error al analizar el contenido JSON', jsonError);

      res.status(500).send('Error interno del servidor');

    }

  });

});
```

Supongo que esto es algún tipo de comportamiento de react-admin que desconozco. Pero necesito que no cree ese campo ID. Capaz puedan sugerirme alguna otra forma de encarar la actualización de los datos.